# UIButton causing unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios

I got the following error when I clicked on the button inside the view (subview) inside the collection view cell -

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7f44cec0a0'

whats is the solution?

My code is -

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = swipeCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SwipeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SwipeCollectionViewCell
        print("colllllll")
        cell.swipeButton.setTitle(collectionArray[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
        cell.selectedAtIndex = indexPath
        cell.swipeButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.swipeButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
        cell.subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.subview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        cell.swipeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTap), for: .touchUpInside)
     //   cell.swipeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTap(indexpath:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

Please provide me the solution.
Thanks

Comment: Add your code for `buttonTap` method.

Comment: First, you're adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that doesn't do anything? Second, setting a `tag` property to `indexPath.row` is a bad approach. Third, you shouldn't be adding gesture recognizers or button action targets in `cellForItemAt` ... that should be part of your cell class itself.